# How to run laravel websocket on heroku

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Im making a simple real-time chat system in laravel and i want it to deploy on heroku. But when i do `heroku run php artisan websockets:serve` it gets me some  error. Is this the correct way to do it?

Here is the console
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its currently not possible as stated here:

> https://help.heroku.com/8R7OO0ZV/can-i-run-a-websockets-server-using-php-on-heroku

Comment: Oh i see sir. Should I find other hosting that supports websockets?

Comment: You would need some host that provides you with root access to the server. Mostly that comes down to a Virtual Private Server (VPS) or a Dedicated Server.